# If $\det(A) = 1$, what are possible values of $\det(\mbox{adj}(A))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, adjoint-operators

If A is square matrix (3×3), and  $det(A)=1$, is it true that $det(adj(A))=1, -1$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if A is ANY $n\times n$ matrix, then $det(adj(A)) = (det(A))^{n-1}$. (how to when A is singular?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/972471/prove-that-if-a-is-any-n-times-n-matrix-then-detadja-detan-1)

Comment: @Sebastiano: $\operatorname{adj} A$ is the better notation, since $A^*$ has too many different meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recall the general formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345517/why-is-it-true-that-mathrmadjaa-deta-cdot-i?rq=1) $A\,{\rm adj}(A) = \det(A)\,{\rm Id}$. Apply $\det$ to get $$\det(A)\det({\rm adj}(A))= \det(A\,{\rm adj}(A)) = \det(\det(A)\,{\rm Id}) = \det(A)^n \det({\rm Id}) = \det(A)^n.$$So $\det({\rm adj}(A)) = \det(A)^{n-1}$, by cancelling $\det(A)$ (when non-zero) on both sides. If $\det(A) = 0$, the conclusion follows from continuity of $A \mapsto {\rm adj}(A)$ and denseness of non-singular matrices. In your case, we get $\det({\rm adj}(A)) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

No. $\det(\operatorname{adj}(A)) = (\det A)^{n-1} = 1$.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Properties